# Motive : This code aims to provide default values to structure members inside structure defination

Tags: c, struct, member-initialization

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct parent_structure
{
    char pe_1 = 'a'; 
};

struct child_structure
{
    int ce_1 = 1;
    int ce_2 = 2;
    int ce_3 = 3;
    struct sample_structure
    {
        int ss_1 = 1 ;
        char ss_2 = 'a';
    } ce_4 ;
    struct parent_structure ce_5;
};

int main()
{
    struct child_structure c_1;
    printf("size of element : %d",sizeof(c_1));

    return 0;
}
```

ERROR:

```
test.c:5:15: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '_attribute_' before '=' token
     char pe_1 = 'a';
               ^
test.c:10:14: error: expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '_attribute_' before '=' token
     int ce_1 = 1;
              ^
```

PROBLEMS:

```
* If i initalize value at the time of defining structure
  it gives the error shown above.
```

I was trying this question for a while and if I initialize values to members of structure like at the time of declaration of structure it shows an error.

Please tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: See reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give default values to struct members in C. Structures are data types.

Just like the way you declare variables `int a;` you declare struct variables like `struct child_structure c_1;`.

Don't confuse `struct` with `struct struct_name`, `struct` itself is not a data type, therefore `struct_name` is not a variable, and therefore you cannot initialize it as you do.